# Solve Troubles Simultaneous equations

Tags: equation-solving

Code copied below. (I know it is not pretty but still learning.) I am trying to solve a system of two equations for two unkowns. In the upper code I solve one equation for one variable and then substitute into the second equation.  This method works and produces a result. (Note I need a numeric solution here not an exact solution.) However, when I try to solve the equations simultaneously Solve returns the result D0->0.  Same issue using NSolve. I am not sure what is going on or how to get "fix" Solve to work with both equations simultaneously.

```
CIn[101]:= (*Problem 5.24*)
Clear["Global`*"]; Clear[Derivative];
D1[Q_, T_, D0_, k_] = D0*Exp[-Q/(k*T)];
EQ1 = D1[Q, 650 + 273.15, D0, 9.62*10^-5] == 5.5*10^-16;
Temp = Solve[{EQ1}, {Q}];
EQ2 = D1[Q /. Temp[[1]], 900 + 273.15, D0, 9.62*10^-5] == 1.3*10^-13;
SolD0 = Solve[EQ2]
EQ3 = D1[Q, 650 + 273.15, D0 /. SolD0[[1]], 9.62*10^-5] == 5.5*10^-16;
Solve[EQ3]

Solve[{D1[Q, 650 + 273.15, D0, 9.62*10^-5] == 5.5*10^-16, 
  D1[Q, 650 + 273.15, D0, 9.62*10^-5] == 1.3*10^-13}, {D0, Q}]
NSolve[{D1[Q, 650 + 273.15, D0, 9.62*10^-5] == 5.5*10^-16, 
  D1[Q, 650 + 273.15, D0, 9.62*10^-5] == 1.3*10^-13}, {D0, Q}]


During evaluation of In[101]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

During evaluation of In[101]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

Out[106]= {{D0 -> 0.0000756184}}

During evaluation of In[101]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

Out[108]= {{Q -> 2.27762}}

During evaluation of In[101]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

Out[109]= {{D0 -> 0.}}

During evaluation of In[101]:= NSolve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

Out[110]= {{D0 -> 0.}}
```

I have tried using Reduce but it just returns False.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Imagine this. If in a fresh notebook I do only `D1[Q_, T_, D0_, k_] = D0*Exp[-Q/(k*T)]; {D1[Q, 650 + 273.15, D0, 9.62*10^-5] == 5.5*10^-16, 
D1[Q, 650 + 273.15, D0, 9.62*10^-5] == 1.3*10^-13}` then I get
`{D0/E^(11.260369815317548*Q) == 5.5*^-16, D0/E^(11.260369815317548*Q) == 1.3*^-13}` When you ask to solve both of those at the same time for D0 and Q you are asking there is a solution that makes both `D0/E^(11*Q)==5.5` and `D0/E^(11*Q)==1.3` true at exactly the same time. The left hand side of both are equal and the right hand sides are different. Does that make no sense at all now?

Comment: Yes and that was because of the typo.  However, even when I corrected that Solve still reported {{D0->0.}}  It did not solve the system until I explicitly took the natural log of both sides of each equation. THe second equation should have 900+273 not 650+273.

Comment: To be clear: Clear["Global`*"]; Clear[Derivative];
D1[Q_, T_, D0_, k_] = D0*Exp[-Q/(k*T)];
Solve[{D1[Q, 650 + 273.15, D0, 9.62*10^-5] == 5.5*10^-16, 
  D1[Q, 900 + 273.15, D0, 9.62*10^-5] == 1.3*10^-13}, {Q, D0}]  does not work. But, Clear["Global`*"]; Clear[Derivative];
D1[Q_, T_, D0_, k_] = D0*Exp[-Q/(k*T)];
Solve[{Log[D1[Q, 900 + 273.15, D0, 9.62*10^-5]] == Log[1.3*10^-13], 
  Log[D1[Q, 650 + 273.15, D0, 9.62*10^-5]] == Log[5.5*10^-16]}] does work.

Comment: History sort of says `Solve` does better with algebraic problems and not as well sometimes with transcendental problems. When you took the `Log` you turned more of your problem into an algebraic problem and `Solve` worked. If you have any idea where the roots might be then `Clear["Global\`*"]; D1[Q_,T_,D0_,k_]=D0*Exp[-Q/(k*T)];eqns={D1[Q,650+273.15,D0,9.62*10^-5]== 5.5*10^-16, D1[Q,900+273.15,D0,9.62*10^-5]==1.3*10^-13};sol=FindRoot[eqns,{{Q,2},{D0,10^-4}}]` works instantly and `eqns/.sol` confirms the solution.  There are also options for `FindRoot` telling it to do more iterations if needed.